# Avoiding duplicate objects in JavaScript dojo

Tags: javascript, memory, object, dojo, memory-leaks

I'm creating an object onfocus of an DOM Element to handle various subsequent events. However, after the element looses focus, I need to destroy the object somehow, so that future focus on the element creates a fresh object with no reference to the original.

Right now, this issue I'm having is that subsequent clicks create another object and all the functions are called twice. Click again, three times. Etc. The code below shows an example of the click event and object creation.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    var videoTopicsHandler = DojoOn(videoTopicsInput, 'focus', function(e){ 
        dropKeyPress(this, 'video-topics');
    });
    var dropKeyPress = function(input, ulId, scroll) {
        var handler;

        obj = new dropDownObj(ulId, scroll); 
        obj.attachEvents(obj, handler, input);
    };
```

Comment: Is this using the dojo toolkit?  If so, you should tag it as such as it's unclear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = null;
var dropKeyPress = function(input, ulId, scroll) {
        var handler;
        if(obj !== null) obj.destroyRecursively();
        obj = new dropDownObj(ulId, scroll); 
        obj.attachEvents(obj, handler, input);
    };
```

Comment: i think there is a typo, replace Recursively by Recursive :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting, you may want to cache those objects you've created and pick them up from cache if it is already there when element regains focus. Pros: faster, no need to regenerate objects on each re-focus and destroy them; cons: unused objects will take memory, but this could be irrelevant if you either go to next page fast enough, or there's small number of those object and re-focusing happens often enough so you'll need them anyway.